# How can react quiz maker work with question array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, forms

I'm using the react native quiz maker (https://github.com/jtalz/react-native-quiz-maker) to make a quiz, and I currently have an array that has all questions in the specified format. However, when I use the below code to display the quiz, I get empty space where the quiz should been. I have a feeling it may be because they require questions = {[{question 1}{question 2}]} where the array is in curly brackets, whereas I simply try to use an array. However, when I tried questions = {{questionList}} I get Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. Any workaround for this?

Here's my code currently, where I have a list of objects, and I put them in into the required question format with a for loop. So, I have questionList, which is an array of objects, where each one is formatted according to quiz maker's format (this part works perfectly, when I try to console.log, I get the output I want)

```js
function Home ({route}) {
  let questionList = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < subset.length; x++) {
    if (route.params.name == 'StoE') {
      let question = {
        questionType: 'Writing',
        question: `What is '${subset[x].spanish}' in English?`,
        answer: subset[x].english
      }
      questionList.push(question)
    } else {
      let question = {
        questionType: 'Writing',
        question: `What is '${subset[x].english}' in Spanish?`,
        answer: subset[x].spanish
      }
      questionList.push(question)
    }
  }
  return (
    <View style={global.container}>
      <Text>{route.params.name}</Text>
      <QuizContainer
        questions={{questionList}}
        onSubmit={(isCorrect) => console.log(isCorrect)}
        onComplete={(progress) => console.log('score: ', progress)} 
      />
      {console.log(questionList)}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add two pairs of curly braces arounds the questions props in ```QuizContainer```. A single pair of curly braces allows you to access JavaScript variables in you JSX.

Comment: Also what's the output of the the `console.log(questionList)`

Comment: @AaditeyNair When I use one pair of curly braces though, I just get a blank quiz, like the place where the question should be is completely blank (my suspicion is that it is taking an empty array for questionList)

Comment: @AaditeyNair The output of `console.log(questionList)` is like `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`, where inside each set of curly brackets is the question, formatted correctly (with properties questionType, question, and answer

Comment: The array isn't empty and is formatted correctly. I can't think of any other reason for this to not work.